# Sencha Getting Started - page loading issue

Tags: extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I currently started learning sencha touch for mobile application development, I have installed the necessary tools also:

1 - jre-7u25-windows-i586
2 - rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p448
3 - SenchaCmd-3.1.2.342-windows.exe
4 - sencha-touch-2.2.1-commercial

and google chrome version: 29.0.1547.66 m

I have also run the generate app command through cmd. and also a xampp server installed already. i am getting page loading issue for GS folder. When i access this: localhost/GS, i can see only that animated page with three white indicators, nothing more. How can i deal with this issue? the link is not redirecting to home page view.

Comment: please add this to comment section

Comment: open Chrome developer console and paste here exception you got

Comment: I am getting these errors: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'append' sencha-touch.js:15453
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wrap'

Comment: @mozilla firefox: showing these errors:

TypeError: head.append is not a function
 

head.append(meta);

sencha-touch.js (line 15453)
TypeError: this.innerElement.wrap is not a function
 

cls: 'x-body'

Contai...4526023 (line 493)

Comment: I solved it with this an answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664821/sencha-touch-application-loader-keeps-blinking/18746658