# Sencha touch application loader keeps blinking

Tags: javascript, ruby, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I just setup an all basic sencha touch application. Just did `sencha generate app *Name* *Directory*`. The app is generated without any error, but when I start the server and load the application in Chrome (just updated to the latest version), I get a blue screen with three blinking dots.

In the JS console, there is this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'append'", occured in sencha-touch.js

Is this a common issue? Did I do anything wrong? The app is generated with sencha touch 2.2.1 and ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: I get the same issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669803/javascript-error-when-run-an-application-example-in-sencha-touch-2-2-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue, and I bet you downloaded at the same time I did.

It turns out the Touch 2.2.1 build from 2013-09-05 23:07:03 had corrupted main js libraries (looks like double content, check out the file sizes), but the current (from 2013-09-06 12:41:24) works as expected for me.

Download the latest version and try again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally new to sencha touch but i had a similar error and solved it:

1) open terminal and navigate to your application-folder (in my case /opt/lampp/htdocs/Testproject)
2) Generate the app (I did it in testing-mode) by: sencha app build testing

3) Go to your browser and navigate to: `http://localhost/Testproject/build/Testproject/testing/`

Done!
That works for me but I have no idea, why the "three-dot-error" appears only on the "root-site" `http://localhost/Testproject`

Anyone know the answer? :)