# JavaScript error when running an application example in Sencha Touch 2.2.1

Tags: sencha-touch

I am starting to develop a mobile application with the lastet Sencha Touch 2.2.1 on Windows 8.
I did the following steps in http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/getting_started.
I started a HTTP Server with command: `sencha fs web -port 8000 start -map [dir_name]`.

When I have opened an application example at `http://localhost:8000/examples/`, it showed properly then I clicked some list. Chrome showed white screen page and error messages in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined sencha-touch-all-debug.js:4882
```

I tried to solve this with these methods:

1. Creating a new app with command: sencha generate app MyApp ../MyApp then run an application example again but it still showed the same error.
2. Changing HTTP Server to XAMPP then ran an application example again but it still showed the same error.
3. Running an application example with Sencha Touch 2.2.0 it work.

What is wrong for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to test in Firefox or safari

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading Sencha Touch 2.2.1 today then it work.
I think that the developer fix this issue already.